# feedback / confirmation pages using cake

Tags: cakephp

whats the best way to implement text feedback after entering the two fields and clicking SUBMIT?

http://nyu.neighborrow.com/items

Comment: If you put more effort and depth into your question, you'll get better answers from people (beyond the stock, "check the manual").  Seriously, the manual covers a lot of this stuff, especially the tutorial.  Also check out ibm developerworks' articles (although they're a little out of date right now, IIRC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Controller you can either set

```
if ($this->Items->save($this->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Your data has been submitted');
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
} else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('Error saving the data');
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/400/setFlash

or

```
if ($this->Items->save($this->data)) {
    $this->flash('Your data has been submitted', '/items/', 5);
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/426/flash

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could redirect to a 'successful completion' page. Some third parties, like eBay, may require you to do this.

Decide how you want *your* application to behave and implement it that way!